# How to use a regular expression to get the following pattern?

Tags: bash

Hello I have the following text:

```
some text,+



this field is another parameter


this is the final of the field


t10681374flp

t10681375flp
```

I would like to match the following two lines:

```
t10681374flp
t10681375flp
```

the rule is that these words begin with 't' and end with 'p',
I tried:

```
grep -e t*p testing
```

however I got:

```
this field is another parameter
t10681374flp
t10681375flp
```

So I really would like to appreciate support to overcome this task,

Comment: `grep -e ^t.*p$ testing` should do it.

Comment: @James Brown thanks I really appreciate the support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using grep, to avoid matching strange lines and the perfect match, the code below

```
grep "^t[0-9]*flp$" testing
```

This matches the below lines,

```
t10681374flp
t10681375flp
```

This doesn't match the lines as below,

```
this field is another parameter
these dont grep
```

Hope you get resolved..

Comment: This will match `tflp` as well - that is, no digits after `t`.  Not sure if that's what the OP intended.  To make sure the pattern matches at least one digit after `t`, you can use this regex: `^t[0-9][0-9]*flp$`.

Answer (score 0):

Following should do the work:

```
grep ^t.*p$ testing
```

`^` indicates begining of the line, `.*` indicates any character
and `$` indicates end of line.